# How to convert BSTR to String with C

Tags: python, c, com, ui-automation

I am developing a function in C to extract the class name of UI element. The function returns BSTR and I want to pass this value to python using Py_BuildValue.

```
BSTR element_class;

hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentClassName(element,element_class);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  arglist = Py_BuildValue("(z)", element_class);
}

if(element_class != NULL)
      free(element_class); ????
```

I am getting the following warning after compiling:

```
'function': 'BSTR *' differs in levels of indirection from 'BSTR'
```

I want to understand this warning and how to do it correctly. Also, I would like to free the memory of this element_class and I do not how to do it as well. I appreciate a lot your help.

**EDIT 1:**
I achieved to delete the warning, just adding $ in element_class. However, when I use the Py_BuildValue, I am getting only the first letter and not the whole name of the class.

Comment: Well SysFreeString() is the function used to free BSTRs. However, IDK what kind of string Python is expecting. A BSTR is a Unicode string. Depends what byte length and encoding that Python expects to use. To convert to a multi-byte string (which is what Windows sometimes calls "Ansi") use WideCharToMultiByte() if you want to convert to a char* type of string.

Comment: Adding `$`?  That can't be standard C.  And a BSTR is UTF-16 encoded, so you'll have to decode it once you get it.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Tks for your help. With my current code I am getting the first letter of class name, it means if the class name is "hello", I am getting only "h". If I understood you well, I have to create a new variable WCHAR and use the function WideCharToMultiByte(). If so, could you please let me know how to use that function, I was checking the documentation from Microsoft and I don understand it. Sorry if the question is fool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte

Comment: Rather than using WideCharToMultiByte, just change your format from "z" to "u".

Comment: Not sure about the implementation you're using, but it *looks* like the `IUIAutomation...()` call requires a *pointer* to the `BSTR` object, so try: `hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentClassName(element, &element_class);` [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-get_currentclassname)

Comment: Looks like @MarkRansom gave the correct answer. The reason you were only getting "h" is because the argument you were using "z" expects a null terminated string: "hello\0". The BSTR would have a format like "h\0e\0l\0l\0o\0\0". IOW, in the string of bytes, between every char is a null, so the function was just seeing the "h" as the totality of the string.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Tks for your explanation about the issue with the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting together all the hints contained in the comments, I think this is what you should be using.

```
BSTR element_class;

hr = IUIAutomationElement_get_CurrentClassName(element, &element_class);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  arglist = Py_BuildValue("(u)", element_class);
}

if(element_class != NULL)
      SysFreeString(element_class);
```

Comment: Tks for your help to consolidate the hints. However, I am getting the following error when I used SysFreeString:  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_SysFreeString. Do you know why?

Comment: @sergioMoreno check the documentation for [`SysFreeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysfreestring).  It says it's part of the library `OleAut32.lib`, which should be automatically linked if you included the proper header.

Comment: I included oleauto.h after windows.h. However, I am still getting the same error. I am using before the following headers #define COBJMACROS and
  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x400. Do you know if I am doing something incorrectly? Tks in advance for your help.

Comment: @sergioMoreno the define of _WIN32_... has to come first.  Other than that I can't think of anything.  Maybe it's time to search the net or ask a new question.